# Efficient method to query multiple tables and combine the results

Tags: performance, t-sql, multiple-tables, cross-apply

I am running a query to pull time series data from approximately 30 tables.  I am downsampling the data to reduce the number of data points and query time.  Each table contains millions of rows and over a dozen columns.  I am only interested in a couple of columns and I calculate a moving average and downsample to 1 hour increments. But I am seeing that as I add tables there is beginning to be substantial time to run the query. This is something that I want to be able to run frequently to update a report, so I need it to run much faster.

What I have tried is nested derived tables and a "cross apply" function to aggregate the results from the tables.

Is there a better method for this to reduce query time?

Currently from these 3 tables it returns 735 rows (15 columns).

```
Select * from
(select
        min([theDate]) as theDate, 
        min([theTime]) as theTime, 
        max([Value]) as maxValue, 
        max([rolling_avg]) as maxDM,
        timeHour as timeHour

from( select [theDate], [theTime], [Value],
       avg(windowAvg) over(order by theDate DESC, theTime rows between 90 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg,
       datepart(hh,theTime) as timeHour
  from (select [theDate], [theTime], [Value], sum([Value]) as windowAvg
          from [Data].[dbo].[tOne]
          Where ([theDate] > convert(DAte,DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())))
          group by theDate, theTime, Value 

          )tOneTemp   
          )tOneTempTwo
          group by theDate, timeHour) tOne 
Cross Apply (select
        min([theDate]) as theDate, 
        min([theTime]) as theTime, 
        max([Value]) as maxValue, 
        max([rolling_avg]) as maxDM,
        timeHour as timeHour

from( select [theDate], [theTime], [Value],
       avg(windowAvg) over(order by theDate DESC, theTime rows between 90 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg,
       datepart(hh,theTime) as timeHour
  from (select [theDate], [theTime], [Value], sum([Value]) as windowAvg
          from [Data].[dbo].[tTwo]
          Where ([theDate] > convert(DAte,DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())))
          group by theDate, theTime, Value 

          )tTwoTemp   
          )tTwoTempTwo
          group by theDate, timeHour) tTwo

Cross Apply (select
        min([theDate]) as theDate, 
        min([theTime]) as theTime, 
        max([Value]) as maxValue, 
        max([rolling_avg]) as maxDM,
        timeHour as timeHour

from( select [theDate], [theTime], [Value],
       avg(windowAvg) over(order by theDate DESC, theTime rows between 90 preceding and current row) as rolling_avg,
       datepart(hh,theTime) as timeHour
  from (select [theDate], [theTime], [Value], sum([Value]) as windowAvg
          from [Data].[dbo].[tThree]
          Where ([theDate] > convert(DAte,DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())))
          group by theDate, theTime, Value 

          )tThreeTemp   
          )tThreeTempTwo
          group by theDate, timeHour) tThree

where tOne.timeHour = tTwo.timeHour and tOne.theDate = tTwo.theDate and tOne.timeHour = tThree.timeHour and tOne.theDate = tThree.theDate
 order by tOne.theDate DESC, tOne.theTime DESC
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: do you know how to use `cross apply`? what you are doing is `cross join` via `cross apply`

Comment: Thank you maSTAShuFu.  I did not know cross join, but it is faster than cross apply for the case that I presented here.